# Show Submit Successful Message After Submit Button Clicked

Tags: visualforce

UPDATE

I am working to add a controller and this is what I have:

[image]

I am getting an error on Intake.Intake__c - I know this is supposed to be PageReference, but how do I call this? My standard controller is Intake__c, and my page name is Intake. Thank you!

---

I have a submit button on my VisualForce page, and I want to show a 'Submit Successful' message if a new object is successfully created, and an error message when it is not.
I'm not sure I actually even have it set to create a new record when Submit is clicked..

Any help, rather than redirections, is appreciated. I've looked [here](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/221885/visualforce-alert-message-after-successful-record-save) and was not able to solve on my own.

My submit button and JS code is here:

```
       </apex:pageblock>
    <br></br> <br></br><br></br> <br></br>
    <input type="button" name="previous" class="previous action-button" value="Previous" />

    <apex:commandButton styleClass="submit action-button" style="width=100px" value="Submit" id="saveButton" action="{!save}" />
     </fieldset>
    
 
</apex:form>

<script>
//jQuery time
var current_fs, next_fs, previous_fs; 
var left, opacity, scale; 
var animating; 





$(".next").click(function(){
    if(animating) return false;
    animating = true;
    
    current_fs = $(this).parent();
    next_fs = $(this).parent().next();
    
    $("#progressbar li").eq($("fieldset").index(next_fs)).addClass("active");
    
    next_fs.show(); 
    current_fs.animate({opacity: 0}, {
        step: function(now, mx) {
            scale = 1 - (1 - now) * 0.2;
            opacity = 1 - now;
            current_fs.css({
        'transform': 'scale('+scale+')'
      });
            next_fs.css({'left': left, 'opacity': opacity});
        }, 
        duration: 800, 
        complete: function(){
            current_fs.hide();
            animating = false;
        }, 
        
    });
});

$(".previous").click(function(){
    if(animating) return false;
    animating = true;
    
    current_fs = $(this).parent();
    previous_fs = $(this).parent().prev();
    
    $("#progressbar li").eq($("fieldset").index(current_fs)).removeClass("active");
    
    previous_fs.show(); 
    current_fs.animate({opacity: 0}, {
        step: function(now, mx) {
            scale = 0.8 + (1 - now) * 0.2;
            opacity = 1 - now;
            current_fs.css({'left': left});
            previous_fs.css({'transform': 'scale('+scale+')', 'opacity': opacity});
        }, 
        duration: 800, 
        complete: function(){
            current_fs.hide();
            animating = false;
        }, 
     
    });
});

$(".submit").click(function(){
    return false;
})


$(document).ready(function () {
$("#datepicker2").datepicker({
dateFormat: "mm/dd/yy",
changeMonth: true,
changeYear: true,
yearRange: "-100:+0"
});

});


$(document).ready(function () {
$("#datepicker").datepicker({
dateFormat: "mm/dd/yy",
changeMonth: true,
changeYear: true,
yearRange: "-100:+0"
});

});

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I created a controller extension and called it within my VF page.

The header became :

```
<apex:page standardController="Intake__c" extensions="IntakeExtension" standardStyleSheets="false" showHeader="false" sidebar="false">
```

and I created an Apex Class to be an extension of Intake that looks like this:

```
public with sharing class IntakeExtension {
    public IntakeExtension(ApexPages.StandardController Intake) {
    }
    public PageReference save() {
        return Page.Congratulations;
    }
}
```