# PageReference in Controller - easy question

Tags: visualforce

UPDATE

In the developer's console, I have input the following:

```
public class Intake {
    public PageReference saveAndRedirect() {

  Intake__c.save(); // This takes care of the details for you.

  PageReference newPage = Page.Congratulations; // This will be the visualforce page or Url that we want to redirect to

  newPage.setRedirect(true);

  return newPage;
}

}
```

I am met with this error: Method does not exist or incorrect signature: void save() from the type Intake__c

It's my understanding this is supposed to act on the save action - What am I doing wrong?

---

I know this is an easy question, but I need help with the syntax.

I'm adding a controller to redirect.
This is what I have.

[image]

I'm getting an error at Intake.Intake__c and am not sure why. I know this should be PageReference, but I'm not sure how to call it. Please help! My standard controller is Intake__c and my page is Intake.

If I change to PageRefernece, I still get an error.

[image]

Comment: Quick note: it's much preferred to use text instead of images when code is involved. Code in an image can't be copy/pasted if your issue is something that people need to try to reproduce to understand/solve, and long horizontal or vertical stretches would make it hard to read without clicking through to the image itself (extra clicks will reduce the number of people willing to help).

Comment: Thanks - I'll keep that in mind - Any info on helping me solve this? Read through David's suggestion and am still confused. Would like some help referencing this particular situation

Comment: As for your new error, the best practice for stackexchange sites would probably be for you to make a new question for it. The short answer to that, though, is that your class doesn't contain a method called "save", hence your error. You have to be precise and verbose in programming. If you're trying to call a method, you either need to define it yourself (inside your class), or get it from somewhere else (like from an instance of the `ApexPage.StandardController` class). Also, the `__c` thing is only for custom SObjects (which are different from a "class" in Apex) and its custom fields.

Comment: In short, I think you might be looking to create a controller _extension_ rather than a controller. Trailhead has many trails and modules to help you learn about new (to you) features and concepts. It also helps to include an abundance of detail in your questions on this site. A controller extension might not be the way to go here, but it's really difficult to give you a push in the right direction if we don't know what your end goal is (i.e. Are you making a visualforce page? looking to use this in a LWC? want to use it to add a button to the detail page for an SObject?).

Comment: Hey, Derek - What I'm looking to do is a simple redirect when a user form is submitted. I have created a VF page that collects and submits user-input to create a new record on my object (Intake) with no issue. However, when the user clicks submit, they are then directed to SalesForce, and I'd like to direct to a 'submitted successfully' page. This doesn't seem like it'd be difficult, but everything I've read says to create a controller extension.

Comment: This is the link to that question [link] (https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/324193/show-submit-successful-message-after-submit-button-clicked)

Answer (score 2):

You've written a method without an enclosing class, which is not legal in Apex. Your method needs to be contained in a controller class.

Returning `PageReference` is correct.

[Create and Use Custom Controllers](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/modules/visualforce_fundamentals/visualforce_custom_controllers) on Trailhead introduces how to build these classes.

Note also that you're using the oldest and worst available UI to write this code. I would strongly recommend switching to Visual Studio Code instead (also introduced on Trailhead), or at minimum use the Developer Console instead of editing Apex in Setup.

Comment: David - I have tried in the developer's console, and am met with this... "Method does not exist or incorrect signature: void save() from the type Intake__c".. Here is what I have in the console. public class Intake {
    public PageReference saveAndRedirect() {

  Intake__c.save(); // This takes care of the details for you.

  PageReference newPage = Page.Congratulations; // This will be the visualforce page or Url that we want to redirect to

  newPage.setRedirect(true);

  return newPage;
}

}

Comment: That's correct, there is no such method. I'd strongly recommend you go through the linked Trailhead module to learn how to write controllers.

Comment: ok. thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

I created a controller extension and called it within my VF page.

The header became :

```
<apex:page standardController="Intake__c" extensions="IntakeExtension" standardStyleSheets="false" showHeader="false" sidebar="false">
```

and I created an Apex Class to be an extension of Intake that looks like this:

```
public with sharing class IntakeExtension {
    public IntakeExtension(ApexPages.StandardController Intake) {
    }
    public PageReference save() {
        return Page.Congratulations;
    }
}
```